# The "php-pdo" package does not have a candidate for installation

Tags: php, pdo, apt, linux-mint-21

I am trying to install wordpress following [this tutorial](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-wordpress-on-linux-mint/) but in the section where I have to install the following

`sudo apt install php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-pdo php-mysql php-zip php-gd  php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath -y`

I have the following output:

```
The php-pdo package is a virtual package provided by:
 php8.2-common 8.2.0~rc5-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php8.1-common 8.1.12-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php8.0-common 1:8.0.25-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.4-common 1:7.4.32-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.3-common 7.3.33-8+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.2-common 7.2.34-36+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.1-common 7.1.33-50+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
  php7.0-common 7.0.33-63+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
  php5.6-common 5.6.40-63+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
You need to explicitly select one to install
E: The package "php-pdo" does not have a candidate for installation
```

does anyone know why this is happening?

pd: i'm using Linux Mint 21

Comment: You might find that installing php-mysql will be enough.